# how to edit register forms for admins with backpackforlaravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

```
-------------------------------------------------------
-- Table `balbine`.`administrator`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `balbine`.`administrator` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(225) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `deleted_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `last_update` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I created an administrator table to replace the user table (laravel), how to edit the registration form to adapt it to the new fields of my administrator table with backpackforlaravel ?

i get error when i tried :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `administrator` (`email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (xxxx@gmail.com, $2y$10$60byaT/oIBTpMQrLYXYCPueaQMewNr.QKJUoioBzwkeO219LJEiSC, 2019-10-27 18:00:57, 2019-10-27 18:00:57))
```

should I move the files from the vendor folder to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
`last_update` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

by

```
`updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

and if you want to call last_update instead of updated_at you can add this on your model

```
class Administrator extends Model
{
// ...

public $appends = [
    'last_update',
];


public function getLastUpdateAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['updated_at'];
}

// ...
}
```

Comment: i used const CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT

Comment: yes but you replace update_at by last_update and this is way it told you this column is not found